# What is the default source of java JRE linux

Tags: java, linux

I am running a JAVA program on linux machine which requires **java JRE 1.8**, The problem is that it only works if I manually add the source `../java32/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/bin` to the `PATH` environment variable.

I want to use the program via ssh using direct access to it

```
ssh user@ip "./program"
```

When accessing via ssh it work since the route isnt added when the program is called (I add it to the PATH manually in the .bashrc file)

I cant find where is the default source set, I tried the following:
1. Running the config:

```
 alternatives --config java
```

It gives the following result as chosen which seems right:

```
 + 3           /opt/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java
```

2. checking /usr/java gives the following connections:

   ```
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Feb 10 16:12 default -> /usr/java/latest
   drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Feb 10 16:16 jdk1.8.0_31
   drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Feb 10 16:12 jre1.8.0_31
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Feb 10 16:17 latest -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31
   ```

Any ideas on what else can be done to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use /usr/java/latest as $JAVA_HOME, that will be in your $PATH automatically in most distros.

To test it:

`ssh user@host "/usr/java/latest/bin/java -version"`

Comment: /usr/java/latest is a directory, $JAVA_HOME points to the correct location already, how do I make the JRE be pointed from $JAVA_HOME? also I see that $JAVA_HOME is set after the ssh so if i check $JAVA_HOME from ssh I get a blank variable

Comment: Or /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java if you need only JRE

Comment: I did it and it still doesnt work, when i run: ssh user@host "echo $JAVA_HOME" I get blank line.

Comment: Have you set up $JAVA_HOME in /etc/profile.d/java.sh?

Comment: There is no java.sh file in that folder, maybe its the problem?

Comment: You should create it with content export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest/jre if you want to use JRE

Comment: I did it and it still doesnt work, I was able to make it work by deleting the `java` file in the old directory now it somehow searches for the java file in the next folders. thank you for your help!

Comment: You mean you deleted the original binary in /usr/bin ?

Comment: No, for some reason there was another JRE path in the environment PATH variable pointing to some weird location, I deleted it from there.